# Kimono - Can't scrape more than 25 pages

Tags: kimono

When doing an API on Chrome Kimono Extension it only let me to choose 25 pages to scrap, even if I choose 100, 500 or 1000 on Kimono Desktop it only scrapes 25 pages...
help please.

Answer (score 1):

I also use the Desktop Kimono and while I tend to limit my APIs page count to ensure consistency, the limit I've set is 500 pages. Definitely more than 25. I've had no troubles so far getting it to do this, so I'm unsure what could be causing it for you.

One thing to ensure though is to make sure you're creating APIs with the desktop chrome extension, not the old web-based Kimono extension.

[kimono desktop Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hmeapcbkmejjfmphikcpgbgakfnjcade)

Best of luck!